# Unity3D Android - Download assets from an API and import on device?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, scenekit

Questions are first then some description which helps explain the questions:

**Questions:**

*Will Unity be able to easily import downloaded assets from our API if we save them in a specified directory with our core Android app?*

*Can we pre-serialize the 3d model assets before uploading them to our API so that they do not need to be serialized by Unity on device? This is so that they load faster*

**Description**

I'm not a Unity/3D developer or an Android developer so apologies if this question doesn't meet community guidelines (I built the API in this scenario). This is also probably very long for what should be simple questions.

We've built an API which serves 3D model files in Collada 1.4 (.dae) format to iOS and Android client applications. File sizes can be quite large (upwards of 80-90mb in some instances) although the majority are in the 4-15mb region.

On iOS we've been having the application download the models from the API and then render them onto the screen via SceneKit which has been relatively simple to achieve. We put the Collada files through a preprocessing step before serving them which converts them into a proprietary format used by SceneKit.

In Android we've encountered any number of problems. We initially experimented with converting models to OBJ instead of Collada and using Rajawali, jPCT and a few other loaders for Open GL ES2.0 but due to our file sizes the time to read and load the models was far too long. We've now decided Unity is probably where we need to go on Android as a rendering engine.

The Android app will consist of two parts, a core app which has an interface for viewing images of the models and downloading the model files and a Unity app which is loaded via an activity from the core Android app to actually render the models.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Workflow.html

Comment: Thanks, precisely what I needed and have been banging my head against a wall trying to find.